# Set android background color async

Tags: android, android-activity, view, background-color

I want to change the background of a activity (or easier the background of a textview) async.

The color should change after a interval (here 500 MS). I can't access the view or the textview by the async class.

Is there any way to do this?

```
private void setColor(int red, int yellow, int blue) {
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red,yellow,blue));
    }

    private class DisplayGradient extends AsyncTask<Clock, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Clock... params) {

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                try {
                    setColor(i*10,0,0);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
                return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Activity.runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

The UI thread is the only thread allowed to manipulate views.

---

Alternatively, use [View.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do something on UI thread
            if(count++ < 10) {
                view.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        }
    }, 500);
```

This uses the UI thread automatically.

Comment: Worked in this way:

`@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Clock... params) {

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                final int c = i * 10;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setColor(c, 0, 0);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way instead of your code. Something like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            try {
                setColor(i*10,0,0);
                Thread.sleep(500)

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     }
};
```

call this line where you want to start

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
```

Comment: This code will `post` the runnable to trigger 10 times at the same moment.

Comment: @F43nd1r code is updated. after finishing for loop the runnable will trigger

Comment: Well, now the code will spawn infinite `postDelayed`calls.